# How to use custom display name when sending e-mail via Microsoft 365 SMTP? (example with PHP Swift Mailer)

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer, microsoft365

I am sending an e-mail using one of our Microsoft 365 accounts.
The account has the following configuration set on MS365:

- Display name: `this should not be displayed`
- e-mail: `example@domain.com`

In my code, I am trying to send an e-mail using `example@domain.com` (which is ok to be displayed) but instead of showing the account's default display name, I want it to say "`Some content relevant name`".

When using this example code:

```
<?php

$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.office365.com', 587, 'tls'))
    ->setUsername('your username')
    ->setPassword('your password');

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
    ->setFrom(['example@domain.com' => 'Some content relevant name'])
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

The e-mails arrive with the display name `this should not be displayed` instead.

How can I set a custom display name when sending emails with MS365 SMTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error on my side, the custom display name works for everybody outside of the organization.